# Proper way to do conditional branching with a tuple

Tags: rust

Let's say we have a closure THAT returns a tuple like this:

```
let closure_process = || -> (bool, Option<usize>) {
  ...
};
```

When the first elements of the pair is true, the second may have some value.
When the first elements of the pair is false, the second is always None.

We can invoke the closure like this:

```
let pair = closure_process();
if pair.0 {
  match pair.1 {
    Some(i) => ...
    None => ...
  }
}
```

Could this be done in a better way with something like "if let" ?

Comment: `Option` already knows whether it has a value or not so the `bool` is redundant.

Comment: true, let's say that when the bool is true, the optiion may have a value.

Comment: You can pattern match on tuples (i.e. `if let (true, Some(_)) = pair` or similar). Whether you do an `if let` or `match` is up to how many branches you need to handle.

Comment: It sounds like you want `Option<Option<usize>>`, which expresses the intent better and prevents mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match the whole tuple:

```rust
let pair = closure_process();
match pair {
    (true, Some(i)) => ...,
    (true, None) => ...,
    (false, None) => ...,
    _ => unreachable!(),
}
```

If you get to decide what this closure returns, you can instead use `Option<Option<usize>>`, which lets you omit the `unreachable!()` branch.

```rust
let pair = closure_process();
match pair {
    Some(Some(i)) => ...,
    Some(None) => ...,
    None => ...,
}
```